# Check db connection is active

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

How can I check that a connection to db is active or lost using spring data jpa?

Only the way is to make a query "SELECT 1"?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. Just execute your query. If the connection has died, either your JDBC driver will reconnect (if it supports it, and you enabled it in your connection string--most don't support it) or else you'll get an exception.

If you check the connection is up, it might fall over before you actually execute your query, so you gain absolutely nothing by checking.

That said, a lot of connection pools validate a connection by doing something like SELECT 1 before handing connections out. But this is nothing more than just executing a query, so you might just as well execute your business query.

our best chance is to just perform a simple query against one table, e.g.:

```
select 1 from SOME_TABLE;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

if you can use Spring Boot. [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) is useful for you. 
actuator will configure automatically and after it has activated ,
you can get know database status to request "health"

```
http://[CONTEXT_ROOT]/health
```

and it will return , database status like below

```
{"status":"UP","db":{"status":"UP","database":"PostgreSQL","hello":1}}
```